# Does there exist a countable metric space which is Lipschitz universal for all countable metric spaces?

Tags: gn.general-topology, mg.metric-geometry, metric-spaces, metric-embeddings

Is there a countable metric space $U$ such that any countable metric space is bi-Lipschitz equivalent to a subset of $U$? How about $c_{00}(\mathbb{Q})$ where $\mathbb{Q}$ is the rational numbers? Thanks!

Comment: Can you define c_00(Q)? (and, by the way, use MathJax [latex] math symbols rather than plain text?)

Comment: @YCor usually $c_0$ are sequences which converge to 0, $c_{00}$ sequences which are eventually 0.

Comment: @FedorPetrov and $(Q)$ means valued in $\mathbf{Q}$? (I'm rather familiar with notation $F(X)$ to mean functions defined on $X$ rather than valued in $X$)

Comment: @YCor I would think so. At least it is a natural try.

Comment: For context Aharoni (1974) proved that every separable metric space embeds bilipschitz into $c_0$ (space of sequences $\mathbf{N}\to\mathbf{R}$ tending to zero, with sup norm).

Comment: Hm. Does any countable dense subset of a Polish space embed bi-Lipschitz to any other?

Comment: Is it clear that the rational Urysohn space doesn't have this property? It seems like a reasonable candidate

Comment: @AlessandroCodenotti it has this property if and only if each countable metric space is bi-Lipschitz equivalent to a metric space with  rational distances.

Comment: @FedorPetrov: If a dense subset of $X$ embeds biuniformly into $Y$, then $X$ embeds biuniformly into the completion of $Y$. So your question has a negative answer.

Comment: @BillJohnson I am afraid that I do not understand your argument. I used to mean "any other dense countable subset  of the same Polish space". Sorry if it was not clear. They all have the same completion of course.

Comment: @FedorPetrov Right, which seems believable to me, but at the moment I can only see the much weaker statement that every metric space is quasi-isometric to one with rational (even integer) distances

Comment: @FedorPetrov. I did not understand what you meant, but your real question also has a negative answer. Take a convergent sequence and its limit. It does not embed into the sequence without its limit.

Comment: @BillJohnson indeed! But if the ground space does not have isolated points, like $c_0$? Say, for $\mathbb{R}$ this seems to be true by standard procedure (add points where the map is defined one by one controlling the tangents).

Comment: @FedorPetrov. Yes, it looks plausible for a separable Banach space, not that I see how to do it for any one other than the real line.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The affirmative answer to this problem follows from

> **Lemma.** For any countable dense subsets $X,Y$ in the half-line $\mathbb R_+=[0,+\infty)$ there exists a $C^2$-smooth function $f:\mathbb R_+\to\mathbb R_+$ such that
>
> $\bullet$ $f(X)\subseteq Y\cup\{0\}$;
>
> $\bullet$ $f(0)=0$;
>
> $\bullet$ $1<f'(x)<2$ for all $x>0$;
>
> $\bullet$ $f''(x)<0$ for all $x>0$.

*Proof.* Such a function $f$ can be found by a standard back-and-forth argument. $\quad\square$

Now take any countable metric space $(X,d)$ and consider the countable subset $d(X\times X)$ of $\mathbb R_+$. By the above lemma, there exists a function $f:\mathbb R_+\to\mathbb R_+$ such that $f(d(X\times X))\subseteq \mathbb Q$, $f(0)=0$, $1< f'(x)< 2$ and $f''(x)<0$ for all $x>0$. These properties of the function $f$ imply that $$f(x+y)\le f(x)+f(y)\quad\mbox{and}\quad x<f(x)< 2x$$for all $x,y\in\mathbb R_+$, and hence the functionn
$$\rho:X\times X\to\mathbb R_+,\quad \rho:(x,y)\mapsto f(d(x,y))$$is a metric on $X$, which is bi-Lipschitz equivalent to the metric $d$.

Thus the metric space $(X,d)$ is bi-Lipschitz equivalent to the metric space $(X,\rho)$ whose metric takes its values in the set of rationals. The latter space is isometric to a subspace of some (canonical) dense subset of the universal Urysohn space.